# ASIHTTPRequest in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, asihttprequest

I have been using iOS 5.1 for a while, today I have decided to upgrade iOS 6. Now, ASIHTTPRequest gives me a lot warnings. Also, couple of my viewController background turns out to black rather than white used to be.

Any i

Comment: The viewController problem is bound to be unrelated to ASIHTTPRequest. You could write that up as a separate issue.

Comment: sorry Thomas, I agree.I have just realized!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest is no longer supported by its original author. I'd suggest moving a newer framework like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas, I will be looking into AFNetworking class. I hope it would be straightforward as much as ASIHTTPRequest!

Answer (score 2):

A lightweight alternative to AFNetworking is [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest).

Drag and drop .h .m and you're done.

```
STHTTPRequest *r = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:@"http://google.com"];

r.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *body) {
    // ...
};

r.errorBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
};

[r startAsynchronous];
```